# ContentDocument parentId

Tags: soql, contentversion, contentdocument, files

I am uploading a file via the Files related list on the Contact detail page.
When I query (SOQL) the database I see the relevant ContentDocument and ContentVersion records.
I would like to get the Contact record Id, with the SOQL query but I can't fine a ParentId field.

How to I get the Id of the record the file was uploaded under?

Comment: you should query attachment object:
select parentId from Attachment;
parentId represents your contact or opp-ty etc.

Comment: I tried query Attachment but I receive no results.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need the `LinkedEntityId` on the `ContentDocumentLink`

Comment: Hi  @Fernando/ @Adrian  , I am struggling uploading file in contentVersion using lightning component. Can any one please guide me with this. Refer to below link for details : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157024/uploading-file-in-contentversion-using-lightning-component

Answer (score 11):

Yes, the documents seem to be out of date?

There can be multiple entries for each ContentDocument. In the case of attachments (Lightning uses ContentDocument for attachments), there will be a record in the ContentDocumentLink for both the UserId and the record that is the Attachments Parent.

You can use a query similar to the below to find details of the attachments relating to an sObject. In this example a Case Id. *Note that the ContentDocumentLink object must be filtered with a where clause.

```
SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId, Visibility, IsDeleted, ShareType,
ContentDocument.Title, ContentDocument.createdDate, ContentDocument.FileType
FROM ContentDocumentLink 
WHERE LinkedEntityId = '5000Y000999MQKTQA4'
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am having the same issue. `LinkedEntityId` seems to default to the userId of the person who uploaded the document.

The `ParentId` field on `ContentDocument` would be ideal, but even though it is in the API guide, it is not available in SOQL or even visible.  The docs say regarding `ParentId` on `ContentDocument`:

> ID of the library that owns the document. Created automatically when inserting a ContentVersion via the API for the first time.
>   This field is available in API version 24.0 and later when Salesforce CRM Content is enabled.